# Do recursive commands like mv cache a file list?

Tags: cache, mv

I want to move the directory content of the folder `foo` at a specific moment including the subfolder structure to another directory. If files are added to the origin folder they should not be moved.

If I run a command like `mv foo/* bar/` and add a file to the folder `foo` while the process is running, which behaviour can be observed?

- file is moved
- file is not moved
- file is moved if the filename is ordered after the filename of the file currently being moved
- other behaviour

Is the behaviour different in Windows/DOS? What's the easiest way to solve the problem described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *caching* because the `mv` command doesn't even see the wildcard.

What happens is that the *command line* expands the wildcard and passes the expanded list to `mv`

So if you had `foo/1' and`foo/2`and`foo/3` then running

```
mv foo/* bar/
```

will expand and *actually* run

```
mv foo/1 foo/2 foo/3 bar/
```

Once the shell has finished the expansion and started executing the `mv` command then any changes to the `foo` directory (eg `foo/4` gets added) won't be part of the command and so will be left behind.

This process is known as `globbing`.

Comment: If dir "1" contains multiple other dirs, do they get expanded too?

Comment: No.  Globbing is not recursive.  If you want recursive then you'd need the `find` command in some form.  But note that if `1` was a directory then `mv foo/1 bar/` _will_ move the whole directory anyway, so you probably don't _need_ recursion here.  The `mv` command doesn't really care :-)

Comment: so does the mv command register change if I add `foo/1/newfile.txt` during the process of the expanded command `mv foo/1 bar/1`?

Comment: Directory moves like this are _atomic_; the `mv` command doesn't recurse down.  It literally moves the whole directory in one action.  So _if_ you can create `foo/1/newfile.txt` then when `foo/1` is renamed to `bar/1` the new file will appear in the new directory.   NOTE: this is not true if `foo` and `bar` are on different filesystems.  _Then_ `mv` has to recurse and a race condition like you're thinking of is possible.  But for a standard _keep on the same disk_ case, there is no race condition.

Comment: in one of my cases the origin and destination are on different filesystems. Does the mv command look for file after file in the subfolder and moves the `newfile.txt` that is existent immediately after the start of the mv command?

Comment: In the recursive case, `mv` doesn't cache anything; it calls `opendir()` then `readdir()` to get each directory entry, then moves the files over one by one.  What happens if the list changes in the middle is not well defined.  You might catch it, you might not.  You'll get an error if you lose the race ('cos it can't clean up the directories after the `mv`).  But it's not deterministic.  You'll want to try and avoid this case by renaming to a directory on the same disk so it's _idle_ and then moving those files to the other disk.

Comment: See also the problem of what happens if a file is _in use_ during this move.  On the same disk the filehandle is moved with the rename so access continues as normal; if you move data to another disk then access remains to a 'ghost' of the old file (inode is open, but no directory entry).